# How can I populate html elements into another page?

Tags: jquery, html, flickr

This is my jQuery function in script.js
This function is use to fetch the feed from Flicker and populate the structure.

I want to populate html structure into another html page called "items.html"

```
$function getImages(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=90528678@N03&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", displayImages);   

  function displayImages(data) {      

// Start putting together the HTML string
var htmlString = '';         

// Now start cycling through our array of Flickr photo details
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
    // Here's where we piece together the HTML
    htmlString += '<div class="item_wrapper" name="'+item.title+'">';
    htmlString += '<img class="item_picture" src="' + item.media.m + '" alt=""/>';
    htmlString += '<div class="item_data">';
    htmlString += '<div class="item_company">';
    htmlString += '<h3 class="fi se en">'+item.title+'</h3>';
    htmlString += '</div>';
    htmlString += '<div class="item_title">';
    htmlString += '<h3 class="fi">'+item.title+'</h3>';
    htmlString += '<h3 class="se">'+item.title+'</h3>';
    htmlString += '<h3 class="en">'+item.title+'</h3>';
    htmlString += '</div>';
    htmlString += '</div>';
    htmlString += '</div>';
});   
     // Pop our HTML in the DIV tag of items.html 
     // Here's the problem. 
    $('div').html(htmlString);
   }
}
```

So how can I do it?
Thanks !!!

Comment: If you still need help with your issue, you should add more information to your post; mainly, what functionality you are trying to provide for your users.  The technical question you are asking is good, but since your experience with HTML and jQuery is newbie (your words :P), there is a good chance you can reach what you are trying to accomplish in other means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version that does work.

```
getImages();
function getImages(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=90528678@N03&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data) {
        var htmlString = '';
        $.each(data.items, function(key, value){
                htmlString += '<div>'+value.title+'</div>';
                htmlString += '<img src="'+value.media.m+'">';
        });
        $('div').html(htmlString);
    });  
}
```

I actually have no idea why your version didn't work.

It could be possible that the callback for getJSON needs to be an anonymous no name function, and that's why the displayImages function isn't working. I couldn't get it to work.

You do have a $ in front of your function declaration. Maybe that contributed to the problem.

Though the html string insert works, like Josh said DOM insertion with nodes is better than html insertion. If you're just looking for a quick and dirty solution html string insertion might be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax load function to load the html contents in your web page.

```
$('div').load("file.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load another html page into an element using:

```
$('div').load("items.html");
```

You also shouldn't use string concatenation to build your dom elements.

Use something like this:

```
var div = $('<div/>');

$.each(data.items, function(i, image) {

    var item = $('<div/>').addClass("item_wrapper").attr('name', image.title);

    $('<img/>').attr('src', image.media.m).appendTo(item);

    item.appendTo(div);

});

$('div').html(div);
```

and so on...

Comment: Thank you sir. but I don't understand. What I'm trying to do is just put the populated html elements into the items.html So later there will be another function call items.html which already has html structure populated from getImages() function.

PS. I'm newbie to HTML and jQuery :)